# Deserialization of JSON, Mismatch

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, deserialization

I am having trouble with my Spring MVC project which involves using an API to pull nutritional facts.  I continue to get a  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch.  Posted below is the JSON response and the classes I have created for the deserialization process.

```
public FullResponse search() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpGet getProducts = new HttpGet("https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/"+ value +"?results=0%3A6&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%2Citem_id&appId=ac23ceb3&appKey=API_KEY");
    CloseableHttpResponse productResponse = client.execute(getProducts);
    String entityString = EntityUtils.toString(productResponse.getEntity());
    FullResponse test = new JSONDeserializer<FullResponse>  ().deserialize(entityString,FullResponse.class);

    return test;
}
```

//This is the full response class

```
public class FullResponse {

String total_hits;
String max_score;
List<Hits> hits;

public FullResponse(){

}

public String getTotal_hits() {
    return total_hits;
}

public void setTotal_hits(String total_hits) {
    this.total_hits = total_hits;
}

public String getMax_score() {
    return max_score;
}

public void setMax_score(String max_score) {
    this.max_score = max_score;
}

public List<Hits> getHits() {
    return hits;
}

public void setHits(List<Hits> hits) {
    this.hits = hits;
}

 }
```

//This is the hits class I have created

```
public class Hits {

   String _index;
   String _type;
   String _id;
   String _score;
   List<Fields> fields;

 public Hits(){

   }

public String get_index() {
    return _index;
}

public void set_index(String _index) {
    this._index = _index;
}

public String get_type() {
    return _type;
}

public void set_type(String _type) {
    this._type = _type;
}

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String get_score() {
    return _score;
}

public void set_score(String _score) {
    this._score = _score;
}

public List<Fields> getFields() {
    return fields;
}

public void setFields(List<Fields> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}


}
```

//And this is my fields class I have created

```
public class Fields {

String item_name;

public Fields(){

}

public String getField(){
    return item_name;
}
public void setField(String name){
    item_name=name;
}
}
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong would be a huge help.

Here is the JSON from the request

```
{
"total_hits":11025,
"max_score":11.122117,
"hits":[{
"_index":"nixproductionv13",
"_type":"item",
"_id":"513fceb375b8dbbc210000e4",
"_score":11.122117,
"fields":{"item_name":"Whole Milk - 1 tbsp"}},

{"_index":"nixproductionv13",
"_type":"item",
"_id":"513fceb375b8dbbc2100017b",
"_score":10.7038355,
"fields":{"item_name":"2% Milk - 1 cup"}},

{"_index":"nixproductionv13",
"_type":"item",
"_id":"513fceb375b8dbbc210000f3",
"_score":10.7038355,
"fields":{"item_name":"1% Milk - 1 cup"}},

{"_index":"nixproductionv13",
"_type":"item",
"_id":"513fceb375b8dbbc210000fb",
"_score":10.689078,
"fields":{"item_name":"Skim Milk - 1 cup"}},

{"_index":"nixproductionv13",
"_type":"item",
"_id":"513fceb375b8dbbc210000e3",
"_score":10.65872,
"fields":{"item_name":"Whole Milk - 1 fl oz"}},

{"_index":"nixproductionv13",
"_type":"item",
"_id":"513fceb375b8dbbc2100017a",
"_score":10.392,
"fields":{"item_name":"2% Milk - 1 quart"}}]}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `flexjson` very well, but it seems like it doesn't like converting from JSON numeric fields to Java `String` fields. The error happens, for example, when trying to deserialize this JSON number

```
"_score":10.7038355
```

into this Java `String` field

```
String _score;
```

If you change all your `String` fields that have corresponding JSON numeric fields into fields of type `Double`, your code will work.

Also note that the `fields` JSON object

```
"fields":{"item_name":"Whole Milk - 1 tbsp"}},
```

is an JSON object, not a JSON array. You therefore need to change

```
List<Fields> fields;
```

to

```
Fields fields;
```

and appropriately also change the getter and setter.

---

Alternatively, you could use a different JSON parsing library, like Gson, which supports these standard type conversions just fine.

Comment: Any ideas why it would still be deserializing and resulting in null product names?

Comment: @user3080107 Yeah, you should use conventional getter and setter names that match the field name. For instance, `setItem_name` and `getItem_name`. Also note that Java naming convention doesn't recommend the use of `_` in variable names. Check out the [Java Bean conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) which many libraries work with.

Comment: The reason behind the naming is because that was what provided by the JSON response, I thought I had use those names otherwise it would be unable to serialize the JSON response

Comment: @user3080107 Each framework has different rules. Some use reflection with the field names directly. Others use the setters. Others use a combination of both or even annotations.

Comment: Everyone has been very helpful.  Im so thankful for a website such as this, I just wish it would not have taken me this long to realize this site existed.

Comment: @user It's pretty great when you use it correctly. Going forward, continue posting as many relevant details as you can when you ask a question.

Comment: I got everything working correctly and once again thank you everyone for all of your help in particular Sotirios Delimanolis, I could not have figured this out without your help.  I dont think I have ever been this excited about finishing a homework assignment

Comment: Actually one last question, I have required fields in my JSP pages and I am also using spring security.  Is there a way I can not require specific forms based on the security role?

Comment: @user It's not exactly clear what you are asking. What do you mean by _required field_?. I also don't have any experience with Spring security. You might want to ask a new question.